# Wallet Pass Update(php)

Tags: php, wallet

I've also tried it without the Content-Type header.

In the log I can see:

> Get pass task (pass type pass.com.spinpos.latest.customercard, serial
>   number 5, if-modified-since (null); with web service url
>   https://my.domain.com/api/loy/wallet/) encountered error: Received
>   invalid pass data (The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.)

Comment: You need to be sending the full, signed .pkpass bundle in your response.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to be missing a description of your problem and some indication of how to reproduce it.